# Why cannot we read the CIL inside .EXE files with a text editor?

Tags: c#, compilation

I know that a C# compiler transforms the C# code into CIL, of which parts are then compiled by the installed .NET's JIT to machine code as needed during runtime.

What exactly does the compiler do, and what is the form of the .exe file that we cannot simply open it with a text editor and read the CIL inside?

Comment: You can read the CIL, if you understand it. It’s all binary so very few people would, especially as characters and not numbers. It’s not any kind of textual code.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why would you expect the EXE/CIL to be human readable text? What would be the benefit of that?

Comment: It's a just lone question asked out of curiosity. In hindsight, I have no idea why I thought the 'real' form of CIL is the one we can see and read after using .net decompilers (or write). As a side question, would you please tell me why an .exe file shows all kinds of characters (from NULL to 'Ě' and 'ś' and '©') rather than the binary code? Is it just because of how Notepad++ interpretes the binary code? (I.E. it takes the .exe's 1010101 and converts to various characters according the selected encoding? Can I select to display it in its "raw" form somehow?)

Comment: `(I.E. it takes the .exe's 1010101 and converts to various characters according the selected encoding` Yes.

Comment: CIL is just machine code for an abstract machine. A CIL disassembler would take those ones and zeros and turn them into human (somewhat) readable assembly language, showing op codes and arguments, etc, the same way that an x86 disassembler could do for a native EXE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native form of CIL is respresented by binary sequences and not a textual, human-readable code.

The readable representation we see is commonly achieved by decompilers, and it is **not** the original form that resides in executable files.